# How can I do that, input: abcde output :12345

Tags: java, char, integer

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String s1 = scanner.nextLine();
char []c1=s1.toCharArray();
for (char c:c1) {
    System.out.print((int)c);
}
```

Output: 979899 from ASCII

I want 12345

Comment: You're going to want to separate the digits or it will get chaotic when the char numbers go above 9

Answer (score 1):

We know that the ASCII code of the letter `a` is 97, for `b` is 98, ..., so to get 1 for `a` then you can substruct `96` from it, now the solution should be;

```
int i = c - 96;
System.out.print(i); // 12345
```